# Ruby: How to load a WSDL file into some data structure?

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, soap4r

I have a WSDL file and want to load it into ruby somehow so I can navigate through it.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  WSDL is just XML, so you should be able to use any XML library to extract information from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to "navigate" through a WSDL file, use any XML parser of your choice.

Chances are what you'd rather after is the easiest way to develop a SOAP client in Ruby.
If that's the case, you should give [Savon](http://github.com/rubiii/savon) a try.